# Excel formula to calculate MIN in table filtered

Tags: excel, filter, dynamic-tables

I have a Table that can be filtered by 1 column values, and want to **create a cell that calculates the MIN when filter is applied**.

| Nº cell | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | car | 2 |
| 3 | Moto | 30 |
| 4 | Moto | 20 |
| 5 | car | 30 |
| 6 | Moto | 4 |
| 7 | car | 10 |

So I can calcualte min with =MIN(B2:B7) , but I want to create a cell to calculate the min in both cases:

Filtering "car" : B will show cells 2,5 and 7 so MIN= 2

Filtering "moto": B will show cells 3,4,6 so MIN=4

Comment: So have you tried minifs() ? you can set one criterion to be "car" or "moto" and then get the min.

Comment: [SUBTOTAL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/subtotal-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939) using `Function_num` 105?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with @Axel Ritcher comment

=SUBTOTAL(105;B2:B7)

Answer (score 1):

Well, just to show the use of minifs():

[image]

```
=MINIFS(B2:B7,A2:A7,D2)
```